# mean and sd on specific data frame is not working

Tags: r

I am beginner in r programming. I have a below problem while trying to find out mean and sd on a specific data frame.

R Package: R i386 3.2.2(32-bit)

Problem:

```
 n <- c(2,3,5)
 b <- c(4,5,6)

 dff <- data.frame(n,b)
 print(dff)
#  n b
#1 2 4
#2 3 5
#3 5 6
 mean(dff)
#[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(dff) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Can somebody point what is wrong in this and how do i correct it.

Comment: What are you trying to find the mean of?  n or b?

Comment: Are you looking for `colMeans(dff)` or `rowMeans(dff)` or `mean(unlist(dff))`? Regarding what's wrong is that `mean` doesn't have a `data.frame` method.

Comment: Hi All,
I was actually referring to below section of example from book(25 recipes ...R)

"A beautiful aspect of mean and sd is that they are smart about data frames. They understand
that each column of the data frame is a different variable, so they calculate
their statistic for each column individually". 

as per the above comments i have tried by creating a dataframe but mean and sd are not working as I have posted in previous request.

can anyone help how do i try it.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the mean of an individual data frame column (if that is your intention), you could use the following to retrieve the means as separate variables:

```
mean_of_n <- mean(dff$n)
mean_of_b <- mean(dff$b)
```

To compute the means of the rows (in list form) use:

```
mean_of_rows <- rowMeans(dff)
```

To compute the means of the columns (in list form) use:

```
mean_of_cols <- colMeans(dff)
```

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the last options?

Comment: None aside from how the output is structured.  As the OP is new to R however I thought it appropriate to provide both the options which sprung to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try also:

```
apply(dff, 2 mean)
```

You can substitute `mean` for any other function and `2` for a `1` if you want to do the operation row wise.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your Question is that R-cookbook was published in 2011 (first edition)at that time the version of R used was R-2.12.1 but after R-3.0 the function mean() was updated as:

> mean() for data frames and sd() for data frames and matrices are
>   defunct

and colMeans() and rowMeans() were introduced.

So when you tried using that new version of R you get error.

for more information check link
[New features in R 3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.0.0/NEWS.R-3.0.0.html)